# Disable WMS service on specific layer through GeoServer REST API

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I have a GeoServer feature layer that I would like to publish only through WFS, thus disabling WMS access.

In the UI, it is possible to selectively enable/disable services for any given layer, as shown in the image:

[image]

How can I do this programmatically, using the GeoServer REST API? I think the API is the `PUT /workspaces/{workspaceName}/layers/{layerName}` described [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#1.0.0/layers.yaml), but from the documentation I cannot understand whether this is actually supported and, if yes, how.

Comment: The best way to discover the correct form of request, is to set up the change in the gui and then request the file via the rest API to see what it looks like

Comment: Thank you Ian for your tip, I figured that the API involved is the "featuretypes", I'm going to post an answer for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that disabling services for a given layer is done operating on the related "feature type" through the [featuretypes API](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#1.0.0/featuretypes.yaml), in particular calling `PUT /workspaces/{workspaceName}/datastores/{storeName}/featuretypes/{featureTypeName}`, passing as body something like:

```json
{
  "featureType": {
    "disabledServices": {
      "string": [
        "WMS"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In case of raster layers, the same thing is done through the [coverages API](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#1.0.0/coverages.yaml).